# Reading CSV File and Deciding on a Data Structure

Tags: python, csv, data-structures, types

I'm working with a rather basic CSV file depicting four cities and the distances between them. As such, the goal is to retrieve the information from said file, and use Python for further operations.

**Excel File**

The file is built up as follows in Excel:

[image: cities.csv file]

**CSV File**

When exported as CSV, the file is represented as follows:

```
,OSL,CPH,LDN,TKO
OSL,0,2,4,10
CPH,2,0,2,9
LDN,4,2,0,12
TKO,10,9,12,0
```

**Getting the Cities**

Evidently, the first row contains all cities, as well as the first blank cell. I have done the following to retrieve the cities, excluding the blank cell:

```
def get_cities(file):
  reader = csv.reader(file)

  cities = []

  row1 = next(reader)
  cities.extend(row1[1:]) #exclude first cell (blank)
  print cities
```

Yielding:

```
['OSL', 'CPH', 'LDN', 'TKO']
```

**Mapping Cities and Distances between Them**

Having done so, I can now read the rest of the file, in order to retrieve the distances between the cities.

**However**, I am finding it hard to come up with a good way of representing this information as a data structure. Optimally, I want to be able to check the distance between any two cities.

Any suggestions on how I can go about implementing this, would be highly appreciated.

That is, **how can I best represent this information** for easy distance lookup?

Comment: Don't you consider using pandas? There is DataFrame inside it.

Comment: I would go with a dict like so : `my_data = {'cities': ['OSL', 'CPH', ...], 'OSL': [0, 2, 4, 10], 'CPH': [2, 0, 2, 9] ,...}`. As @AntonGlukhov says, pandas can do that for you easily, but so can you.

Comment: Please, take a look at pandas.DataFrame.from_csv classmethod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like your data directly represents an adjacency matrix for a graph.Store it as a adjacency matrix and just do simple lookup for (city1, city2) for the distance. For implementation you enumerate on the city.

Comment: Searching SO for adjacency matrices, it looks like the most common way is to store this information as a 2D array? If so, I will try that. 
When mentioning to "enumerate on the city"; what exactly does that entail? By example, would OSL = 1, CPH = 2, etc. ?

Comment: yup same, store it as a 2-d array and for the lookup use those enumerations

Answer (score 0):

Use dict of dicts. This is not very memory efficient but is the simplest solution using built in python containers.

```
    map = {'OSL' :
        {
            'OSL' : 0,
            'CPH' : 2,
            ...
        },
     'CPH' :
        {
            ...
        },
     ...
    }
```

Then you can look up the distance just like map['OSL']['CPH'].